# Loop isn't working correctly

Tags: php, html, pdo

I made a loop to create 6 tables in HTML, and I want it to populate some appointments from my database.

Here is the code:

```
require_once 'class_php/Patient.php';
$patient = new Patient();
$patient->Connexion();

$datedujour = date("Y/m/d");
$demain = date("Y/m/d", strtotime("+7 day", strtotime($datedujour)));

$requete = "SELECT heuredebut , jour FROM dispo_base";
$resultat = $patient->LectureSql($requete);

$ligne = $resultat->fetch();
$nbtab = 5;
$h = 0;
while ($h <= $nbtab) {

echo"<table style='display: inline-table'>";
if ($ligne['day'] = 1) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<th>Monday</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
} elseif ($ligne['day'] = 2) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<th>tuesday</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
} elseif ($ligne['day'] = 3) {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<th>wednesday</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
while ($ligne = $resultat->fetch()) {

    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td><a>";
    echo $ligne['heuredebut'];
    echo"</a></td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$h++;
}
```

My loop works and creates 6 table. BUT all the table has is the name "Monday" and when I try to fill it with my second while, it fills only one table and I want to fill it with all records in my DB.

How can I select where the records go?

Thanks you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I say to $ligne['day'] to read the number 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a quick response ...

```
if ($ligne['day'] = 1) {
if ($ligne['day'] = 2) {
if ($ligne['day'] = 3) {
```

shouldn'd be

```
if ($ligne['day'] == 1) {
if ($ligne['day'] == 2) {
if ($ligne['day'] == 3) {
```

??

Comment: Now he create 6 table, but only one is filled with a name and records, the others are totally empty.

Comment: Yes, `$resultat` should be sorted by `day`. And only one `while` loop is needed.

Comment: You think I need to redo the $resultat->fetch() ? like that $resultat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ?